# Binary file read - write not working

Tags: c, pointers, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I've been trying to write a binary file with some information in a program but I can't make it work. I write it and try to read it to see if it worked. This is the struct I'm trying to write inside the file:

```
typedef struct{
    int puntuacio;
    int posicio_x;
    int posicio_y;
    int vides;
    int direccio;
}Jugador;
```

I've got a variable called `player` of type `Jugador`. In the function I work with the binary file I recieve `player` as a pointer (so `Jugador *player`). This is the code I've written (I only give the relevant parts):

```
f=fopen("whatever.bin","wb+");
fwrite(nom,sizeof(char),strlen(nom),f); //nom is a string containing the player's name
fwrite(&player,sizeof(Jugador*),1,f);
auxint=player->direccio; //just doing this to see if I pass the info correctly
fwrite(&auxint,sizeof(int),1,f);

//auxp, auxjug and auxint are auxiliar variables I declared inside the function
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET); //go to the start of the file before reading
fread(auxp,sizeof(char),20,f);
fread(&auxjug,sizeof(Jugador),1,f);
fread(&auxint,sizeof(int),1,f);

printf("auxp:%s--\n",auxp);
printf("puntuacio:%d--\n",auxjug.puntuacio);
printf("dir:%d--\n",auxjug.direccio);
printf("posx:%d--\n",auxjug.posicio_x);
printf("posy:%d--\n",auxjug.posicio_y);
printf("vids:%d--\n",auxjug.vides);
printf("auxint:%d--",auxint);
```

`auxp` prints the name correctly but I get an additional garbage character in the last position of the string, but that's easy to solve. `auxint` prints perfect. But I get what I guess are memory adresses when I print the parameters of `auxjug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fwrite(&player,sizeof(Jugador*),1,f);
```

is only writing a pointer size element (4 or 8 bytes) to the file.  You need to have:

```
fwrite(player,sizeof(Jugador),1,f);
```

without the extra `&` and the extra `*`.

Another problem is that you only output `strlen(nom)` bytes to the file.  But when you read the file, you read exactly 20 bytes.  So you should probably pad your `nom` string to 20 bytes and fwrite exactly 20 bytes to the file:

```
fwrite(nom,sizeof(char),20,f);
...
fread(auxp,sizeof(char),20,f);
```

Comment: @user2952272 See my edit.  You need to output 20 bytes for the name if you plan on reading 20 bytes from the file later on.

Comment: @user2952272 See my latest edit.  I didn't notice that `player` was a pointer.  So you need to not use the '&' when you fwrite to the file.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, but I already solved it. Thanks anyway.